# Center values under others

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have tried to center the value (number + %) under the "Battery L" and "Battery R". 
For example:

```
Battery L    Battery R
  100%         100%
```

Do you know how can I do?

```
<View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end", alignItems: "flex-end", marginRight: 20 }}>
      <Text style={{}}>{"Battery R"}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
      <Text style={{}}>{"Battery L"}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>

  <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
      <Text>{"100" + " %"}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
      <Text>{"100" + " %"}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-haze-1ffnv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using simple style guide as below

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
  <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>{"Battery L"}</Text>
    <Text>{"100" + " %"}</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>{"Battery R"}</Text>
    <Text>{"100" + " %"}</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

This may not be the optimal solution.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 0):

try flex:auto
you might find more here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

Comment: instead of using flex: 1? beacuse of it doesn't change :(